# How to check Expiration for Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API 3.0. We are not including the notificationField. It has always used the default settings setup in the Admin for DocuSign. How can I confirm the expiration on an envelope?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be better if you could clarify your question by providing more context and some example code. You can take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP API Doesn't appear to have a way to get Reminder and Expiration settings for an active envelope. You could log in to the web console, Correct an envelope and view them there.

For the REST API, There's a post about this on the [DocuSign Developer Blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-trenches-reminders-expirations/): An API call to the [Envelopes::getNotificationSettings](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/getNotificationSettings) method will do it.

`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/notification` returns the relevant information.

Comment: Thank you Drew. It looks like they are defaulted to the DocuSign defaults not to my admin portal settings.  As an partner/integrator we only have a demo account. Do you know if the expiration/reminder work in the demo environment?

Comment: Reminders and Expirations are fully configurable in both Demo and Prod. If yours aren't being applied, I'd recommend posting a new question with the full body of your API call.